# Regular expression to search for files and folders

Tags: c#, regex

Help write a regular expression to search for files and folders,
searches for a given mask. In the mask, you can use "*"
(any characters in any number), and the "?" (one symbol).

Comment: I would suggest you provide examples of what you *have* tried, or at least provide examples for what you're looking for. Your language is very unclear.

Comment: I need a regular expression that lets you check the text to a file or folder.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to find all folders/files with a specified name?

Comment: I need a universal expression that allows you to search for files with different extensions and at the same time and folders.

Comment: Excuse me. I'm going to learn English, and then go back))

Comment: @Lightness you can make your question better by editing it with specific examples rather than specifying you "need" something. This site is here to help guide you to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) shows you how to use regex in C#.
You could always just loop the directory that you're looking in and check the file names instead of making a regex. (You'll need to use System.IO)

Perhaps something like this?

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory); 
Regex regex = new Regex("target file name");
Match match = regex.Match(string.Join(" ", fileEntries););
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```